# React Jest/Enzyme: Mock/Override a Response of ES6 Class Method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I wanted to write a unit test (using `Jest/Enzyme`) for login page which is written in `React` and I tried to Mock the **server response**, so I can test if the login form works correctly.

I have a React **class component** like this:

```
// LoginPage.js

export class LoginPage extends Component {

    // ...

    handleClick = async () => {
        
        const username = this.state.username;
        const password = this.state.password;

        const result = await callServer(username, password); // "fetch" used here

        console.log('Server Response:', result);

        if (result) // redirect

    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Wrapper> // Styled Components
                
                <Input type="text" id="loginUsername" ... />
                <Input type="password" id="loginPassword" ... />

                <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Submit
                </Button>

            </Wrapper>
        )
    }

}

export default withRouter(MyClass);
```

And my test file:

```
// LoginPage-test.js

import React from 'react';
import {configure, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import {LoginPage} from './LoginPage';
import Input from './Input';
import Button from './Button';

it('test the login page', async () => {

    const wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage/>),
          inputUsername = wrapper.find(Input).findWhere(n => n.prop('id') === 'loginUsername'),
          inputPassword = wrapper.find(Input).findWhere(n => n.prop('id') === 'loginPassword'),
          loginButton = wrapper.find(Button).findWhere(n => n.prop('children') === 'Submit');

    inputUsername.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'loginUsername', value: 'test_user' } });
    inputPassword.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'loginPassword', value: 'test_pass' } });

    const result = await loginButton.props().onClick();
    wrapper.update();

});
```

With this test I can see the Server Response (`console.log`) and the test passed. But I don't want to call the real server (as it's not a good practice in testing), instead I wanted to Mock the `handleClick` response.

I tried many ways, with `spyOn`, `mockImplementation` and so on without success. These are some of my tries:

```
// ------------------ (1) ---------------------

jest.doMock('./LoginPage', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            __esModule: true,
            ...(jest.requireActual(LoginPage)),
            LoginPage: {
                handleClick: async () => {
                    console.log('MOCK_TEST');
                    return new Promise.resolve('MOCK_TEST');
                }
            }
        };
    });
});

it('test the login page', async () => { ... });

// ------------------ (2) ---------------------

it('test the login page', async () => {
    
    // ...

    inputUsername.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'loginUsername', value: 'test_user' } });

    jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleClick').mockImplementation(() => {
        console.log('MOCK_TEST');
        return 'MOCK_TEST';
    });
    wrapper.update();

    // ...

});

// ------------------ (3) ---------------------

jest.mock(LoginPage, jest.fn());
LoginPage.mockImplementation(
    () => ({
        handleClick: () => {
            console.log('MOCK_TEST');
            return 'MOCK_TEST';
        }
    })
)

it('test the login page', async () => { ... });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
const handleClick = jest.spyOn(LoginPage.prototype, 'handleClick).
mockImplementation(() => {
    //your mock
}
```

and

```
expect(handleClick).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Remember that `jest.spyOn` works only with normal functions and NOT with arrow functions. Also, you should set the spy before mounting your test component.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should change my Arrow Function to Normal Function in the component too, so it works now. Please edit your answer for others to know, so I can Accept it.

Comment: And it should be declared **before** `const wrapper = shallow(<LoginPage/>);`